# JOliver EventStore dispatched flag not set, events replayed on each restart

Tags: c#, neventstore

I'm using EventStore and things appear to be working, the event is stored and dispatched by my in-memory broker, the event is processed by my read model.  But the "dispatched" flag in the EventStore Commits table is not getting set for some reason, so each time I restart my app it replays all of the events.  I'm using SQL Server 2012 as the store.  No errors are occurring.  Any idea why this flag would not be getting set?

My code:

```
   private static IStoreEvents BuildEventStore(IBroker broker)
    {
        return Wireup.Init()
            .UsingSqlPersistence(Constants.EventStoreConnectionStringName)
            .InitializeStorageEngine()
            .UsingJsonSerialization()
            .Compress()
            .UsingAsynchronousDispatchScheduler()
            .DispatchTo(new DelegateMessageDispatcher(c => DispatchCommit(broker, c)))

            .Build();
    }

    private static void DispatchCommit(IBroker broker, Commit commit)
    {
        foreach (var @event in commit.Events)
        { 
            if(!(@event.Body is IDomainEvent))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("An event was published that is not an IDomainEvent: " + @event.Body.GetType());
            }

            broker.Publish((IDomainEvent)@event.Body);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UsingAsynchronousDispatchScheduler` wires in a dispatcher that does its own thing out of the mainline of your processing. For example, if it has issues writing, the command processing thread is not going to hear about it.

One way of making life <strike>simpler</strike>different is to change it to synchronous so your command processing chain gets to hear about the exceptions (remember that a dispatch exception doesn't roll back the fact that the command got processed and the event has now happened though).

But really you need to USL to see what the processor wired in by `UsingAsynchronousDispatchScheduler` does wrt reporting problems so that your monitoring can pick up the issue.

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for the answer. I didn't understand the last statement ("But really you need to USL...").  Could you elaborate at all?

Comment: Oh, sorry, must go easy on the TLAs. Use the Source Luke. I mean get familiar with the codebase in order to figure out the real answer in short order - its short and tidy so there's no excuse not to

Comment: i.e. I might be able to guess that the Wireup allows you to supply a dispatch problem sink or go look at the code for you, but you're far better off teaching yourself to fish right now if you'll pardon some bad puns and mixed analogies to go with the acronym soup :P

Comment: Yes agreed, was just hoping for an easy "you forgot this etc..." since I'm not very experienced w/ EventStore other than playing around with it.  But you are right, should just take a look.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I did switch over to the synchronous dispatcher and my issue surfaced (missing update permission on my commits table).  Thanks again.

Comment: Have a good think whether you want to make the dispatching sychronous permanently though. Be sure to read Jimmy Bogard's posts from a few months back as food for thought. While there may be a lot to be gained from even doing all Event Processing/Projection including Denormalizing during Command Processing.

Comment: However note that none if this changes the fact is that the event being Dispatched has simply happened and whether/when it gets Dispatched (e.g. retries etc.) is immaterial - any new commands will work against the updated state but the Projection side will not be consistent until the Dispatching and processing is complete. You have lots of options and one size will not fit all (possibly even within a single system) so I won't even try!

Comment: Also remember the Dispatcher hook will (e.g. if a Dispatch didn't get completed prior to last shutdown or you have competing dispatchers) potentially see all kinds of Events, not all necessarily related to the Command that you're processing right now. (which is also why everything feeding Commits into a given EventStore needs to have the format information/capability to handle any event that anyone may have put into said Event Store)

Comment: Forgot the @swannee so you see my rantings!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the info I've been considering many of these things.  Did switch back to async btw after finding the issue, but good to know that switching this on will help identify issues.